# GitLab pipelines have stopped working as expected

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

GitLab pipelines have stopped working as expected. They were working fine for over a year. Now, two issues have arisen:

1. If push old branch - the pipeline does not appear automatically. It now needs to be manually added by clicking the 'Run pipeline' button.
2. If push newly created branch - the pipeline does not appear at all and returns the error message: 'Pipeline cannot be run. Reference not found'."

.gitlab-ci.yml

```
variables:
  DOCKER_REGISTRY: xxx
  APP_DEFAULT_REGION: xxx
  APP_NAME: xxx
  GIT_STRATEGY: clone

stages:
  - image
  - deploy

create image:
  stage: image
  tags:
    - git
  except:
    refs:
      - prod
  when: manual
  before_script:
    - aws --version
    - docker --version
    - aws ecr get-login-password | docker login --username AWS --password-stdin $DOCKER_REGISTRY
  script:
    - docker build -t $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID .
    - docker push $DOCKER_REGISTRY/$APP_NAME:$CI_PIPELINE_IID
........
```

GitLab version 14.9

Comment: Pretty strange. I would check the GitLab server logs for errors. Make sure the disk isn't full on the system, too... Without knowing what has changed on the system since before this behavior started, it's hard to say what the cause might be.